# Change type of variable inside a class doesn't seem to work in Docker

Tags: python, docker, containers

I'm trying to write software for my student radio and I've been desperately stuck for 3 days with a strange bug.

My software launches an `FFmpeg` process which streams to an ice cast server. No problem it works, but the issue comes when I tried to close this process in another method of the class where the process is an attribute:

```py
class IcecastHandler():
    def __init__(self, base_url, username, password):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.test = 0
        #printWithTime(id(self.p))
        self.p = None

    def stream(self, mountpoint):
        self.test = 1
        try:
            self.kill()
        except: 
            printWithTime("No SOS stream playing, launching one...")
        try:
            print(self.username)
            print(self.password)
            print(self.base_url)
            print(mountpoint)
            
            self.p = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", "http://icecast.radio24.ch/radio24-rc-96-aac" ,"-f", "mp3", "icecast://" + self.username + ":" + self.password+ "@" + self.base_url +  mountpoint], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=False) 
            print("Id de p apres sa creation" + str(id(self.p)))
        except Exception as e:
            printWithTime("An error occured when launching the stream :")
            printWithTime(str(e))
            raise
```

The code above works, (pretty awful maybe ? ^^) but when I try to kill the process :

```
def kill(self):
    #printWithTime(id(self.p))
    print("Type de p kill" + str(type(self.p)))
    print("Id de p kill" + str(id(self.p)))
    try:
        self.p.poll()
    except Exception as e:
        printWithTime("Error occured while checking if there is a subprocess alive:" + str(e))
        #raise
    else:
        if self.p.poll() == None: 
            self.p.terminate()
        printWithTime("Stream killed")
```

The strange part is that I have tried to print id of p in the 2 methods, and it is different, but only if I run the script in a docker container, when I run it directly on my computer I have no problem, `self.p` is the same object in the 2 methods (same id, same type) but when I run it inside a container, it is the same object in `kill()` and `__init__` but a different one in `stream()`....

Edit :
I use Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4 and here's my Dockerfile :

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx:python3.8-alpine
RUN apk --update add bash nano
ENV STATIC_URL /static
ENV STATIC_PATH /var/www/app/static
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg
```

Edit 2 :
Here's some log :
[21:37:49]After launching the stream : 140192757676496 (that's the ID of my object)

Here's the content of this object
[21:37:49]{'base_url': 'something', 'username': 'something', 'password': 'something', 'p': <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f812c88c7c0>}

[21:38:12]Before stopping the stream : 140192757676496
[21:38:12]{'base_url': 'something', 'username': 'something', 'password': 'something', 'p': None}
But the stream (launched in process p is however still running...)

Comment: Whats the output you're getting? Docker sometimes doesn't like Popen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714478/python-subprocess-popen-not-working-in-a-docker-container-works-fine-locally

Comment: I print the output of FFmpeg and there is not issue, it start well, what can log can I show you to help ?

Comment: a) "when I run it directly on my computer" - do use Linux or other OS? b) it  makes sense to show Dockerfile for docker-related question, c) do you create virtualenv for your application? d) can you `docker run -it [your docker image] sh` and then try manually start application inside docker? what do you see?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post.
When I do it, it doesn't like it because of the connectivity on port 80 already used inside the container but it works the same way (everything except stopping this process)

Comment: How is it that `self.p` has any value at all in `__init__`, as that's `self`'s constructor?  What are the types that you get for `self.p` in the two cases?  How does the call to `kill` relate to the call to `stream` in terms of the lifetime of the `IcecastHandler` involved?  You aren't talking about the call to `kill` from within `stream`, are you?  If you are, then it's no mystery why the two are different...you call `kill()` before reassigning to `self.p`, but then within `stream`, you print the `id` of `self.p` only after reassigning it a new value.

Comment: In the kill function it is always a none type whether I call it before or after the reassignment .
I call kill() after from a flask route to kill the stream once everything ok but also before streaming to be sure there is no stream launched otherwise I have issues

Comment: There's something going on that we can't see here if you are suggesting that upon creating an instance of `IcecastHandler`, the code reports a non-None value for `self.p`, but then when you call the `kill` method shown on that same object, `self.p` is None.  Something has to be going on between those two samplings of `self.p`.  There is fundamentally no way that `self.p`'s type can change just because it's being viewed in one method of an instance vs another.  There has to be more going on than that. - Can you post code that demonstrates this behavior in a complete execution?

Comment: Another strange similar fact is that if I assign self.volume in a method in the audio_monitor object and then I try to access audio_monitor.volume I get the class default value and not the new value assigne, but also only in docker container it works well if I just run the python script

Comment: Actually the first time I call kill (i.e inside the stream function) its a none type, then I reassigned it and it become a Popen Type or something like that, and then when I try to call kill function, of the same object but from a flask route from example it appears to be a none type (And the id of the object is the same... so it the same object I think...)

Comment: There has to be something else going on here that none of us is seeing yet.  There's nothing at all special about a Docker environment.  It's just Linux and Python, and that environment should behave in just as predictable a fashion as does the MacOS equivalent. - If you're checking the ID of the object, then you're looking in the right direction.  I can't think how two objects with the same ID can have different types.  Truly strange.

Comment: I think that the problem should be started smaller, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: for troubleshooting, maybe print all the attributes of an instance of your object via `__dict__` https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-all-the-attributes-of-an-object-in-python

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I try this tomorrow and I'll come back here :)

Comment: Well, I have use __dict and here's my weird log (it's actually print() with add of time)
I put the log on the post